# TensorFlow apply a function to each row of a matrix variable

Tags: r, tensorflow

Hi I'm a newbie to Tensorflow. What I want to do is something like this in R:

```
mat = tf$Variable(matrix(1:4, nrow = 2))
apply(mat, 1, cumprod)
```

Is this do-able in Tensorflow, either in Python API or R tensorflow package? Thanks!

EDIT: `tf$cumprod` is actually what I want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The TensorFlow Python API includes the [`tf.map_fn(fn, elems)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn) higher-order operator, which allows you to specify a (Python) function `fn` that will be applied to each slice of `elems` in the 0th dimension (i.e. to each row if `elems` is a matrix).

Note that, while `tf.map_fn()` is very general, it may be more efficient to use specialized ops that either broadcast their arguments on one or more dimensions (e.g. [`tf.multiply()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/math_ops/arithmetic_operators#multiply)), or reduce in parallel across one or more dimensions (e.g. [`tf.reduce_sum()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/math_ops/reduction#reduce_sum)). However, `tf.map_fn()` is useful when there is no built-in operator to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have a problem here, when I set the entropy from scipy as the argument it raises an error. Is it obligatory to not call any function of a library?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I which to generalize this problem into something more specific (map a function on all the depth channel associated with every pixel). Could you help me, please? I asked my question in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59094897/map-function-on-each-pixel-of-a-3d-tensor  

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: It would have been nice to provide the code that actually solves the OP's question regardless of efficiency considerations.